# Can't get shell if I remove 'command' from docker-compose

Tags: django, docker

Here's how I want to run my container with the following commands:

```
docker-compose up -d --build

docker compose up -d

docker exec -it app_api bash
```

From there I will have a shell where I can run `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` or `makemigrations` etc.

This docker-compose runs if I uncomment the 'command' line. However, I don't want `runserver` to run automatically, I just want the shell.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    web:
        container_name: app_api
        build: .
        # command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/project
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        depends_on:
            - db
      
    db:
        image: postgres
        container_name: app_db
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

WORKDIR /project

COPY requirements.txt /project/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /project/
```

Comment: Your Django container does not run on `docker-compose up`, sounds like you got what you wanted? You can't exec into a container that's not running - use `docker-compose run --rm web bash` to start a web container and run a command

Comment: Why don't you want your application to run when you start the container?  Consider a workflow where you run `python` to get a REPL, then manually run `main()` in it; you wouldn't usually do that manually every time you wanted to run your application, you'd run `./manage.py` as a script.  I'd similarly make your image's default `CMD` be the Django server and ignore an interactive shell here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Dockerfile for the python image, which you can find [here](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/master/3.9/bullseye/Dockerfile), you'll see that it has a CMD statement of

```
CMD ["python3"]
```

That's what gets executed when you don't override it. The trouble is, that only really makes sense when running the container in interactive mode. When you run it detached it sees that there's nothing to do, so it exits immediately and the container stops.

To get your container to run interactively, you can change your service definition to

```
web:
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    container_name: app_api
    build: .
    # command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
        - .:/project
    ports:
        - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
        - db
```

By setting `stdin_open` and `tty` to true, you'll run the container interactively. It's equivalent to specifying `-it` on a `docker run` command.

If you don't want your container to start up interactively right away, but prefer that your container starts up detached so you can `exec` into it, you can use a simple 'do-nothing forever' command like this

```
command: tail -f /dev/null
```